# python iterate over one key and if a cond is met then do something else with the other keys

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a the following dict:

```
my_dict = {'h': 13.4 , 'geneName': TaT , 'mode': poor, 'depth': 5, 'detection': bad}
```

I would like to output only the geneName and detection if the mode is poor.  The following doesnt work as I iterate over mode and then once the condition is met I cant go back to geneName.  I tried storing the mode into a list and then call it later but that was messy.  any ideas please?

```
for k,v in my_dict.iteritems():  
  if k == 'mode':   
    if v == 'poor':    
      if k == 'geneName':
        gene_name = v    
          if k == 'detection':
            detection = v
```

Comment: Do you have just one dictionary or a list of dictionaries?

Comment: Just one, thanks it works

Answer (score 2):

If you have only one dictionary, just fetch the key values directly:

```
if my_dict['mode'] == 'poor':
  print my_dict['geneName']
```

If you have a list of dictionaries, put this if statement inside a for loop:

```
for d in listOfDicts:
  if d['mode'] == 'poor':
    print d['geneName']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
>>> my_dict = {'h': 13.4 , 'geneName': 'TaT' , 'mode': 'poor', 'depth': 5, 'detection':'bad'}
>>> if my_dict.get('mode') == 'poor':
...   print my_dict.get('geneName'), my_dict.get('detection')
... 
TaT bad
```